# Wordpress database connectivity error on update

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys I updated my WordPress (by mistake) to 4.7 and all the pages which were fetching data from db are messed up.

I can revert back to my original version but I want to continue working on wp 4.7 and fix this error....

upon googling this term **p3pnexwpnas** i found out that this happens

Kindly take a look at some of the errors             `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'fetch - <b></b><br>---<br> Query: select * from wp_22v51hy4p7_revslider_settings' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/functions.class.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(22): UniteFunctionsRev::throwError('fetch - <b></b>...', -1) #1 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(36): UniteDBRev->throwError('fetch - <b></b>...') #2 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(127): UniteDBRev->checkForErrors('fetch') #3 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_params.class.php(42): UniteDBRev->fetch('wp_22v51hy4p7_r...') #4 /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_op in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/functions.class.php on line 7`

also this is an error on a different page:-

```
Notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in     /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-config.php on line 23

Notice: Constant DB_USER already defined in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-config.php on line 26

Notice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-config.php on line 29

Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-config.php on line 32

Notice: Constant DB_CHARSET already defined in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-config.php on line 35
```

any hint to solve this problem will be appreciated thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in Wordpress installation and database. 
The problem is that there are some plugins which are not compatible with wordpress 4.7.

have a look at first error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'fetch -
>   Query: select * from wp_22v51hy4p7_revslider_settings' in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas09_data01/09/2724709/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/functions.class.php:7
>   Stack trace: #0

It's because `revslider plugin` which is not compatible with your current version of wordpress that's why it's throwing fatal error. So if want to continue work on wordpress remove all the plugin which are not compatible with your wordpress version otherwise update it.

Comment: @user287332. I think all the errors are due to plugin no other errors are there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer....

So there were 2 problems

1. deprecated plugin error
2. Used include so it was loading the wp-config file twice

The old dev used include for including the wp-config that is the reason constant already defined was coming. I used require_once and this problem was solved.

Thanks for the plugin help guys....